# Extra attribute in many to many join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a many to many association between `User` and `Todo` through a join model called `UserTodo`

Of the many users a todo has, there's one *owner*. So, I created a column in the `user_todos` join table called `is_owner`.

Question is, how do I populate this attribute while creating a Todo?

Currently, I'm creating the todo, then separately updating this attribute in `TodoController#create` action.

```
@todo = current_user.todos.create(todo_params)
@todo.user_todos.first.update_attribute(:is_owner, true)
```

This seems wrong. Is there a single call I can make to populate this attribute while creating the `todo`?

Second, is there a way to query if a user is an owner of a todo, this way?

```
current_user.todos.first.is_owner?
```

Comment: Do you have associations between `UserTodo` and the other two models? You should be able to just is the accessor like so `@todo.user_todos.first.is_owner = true`. Does that work? If not, please update the question with the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a user_todo.rb file with a UserTodo class and do stuff like:

```
ut=UserTodo.new
ut.todo = Todo.create(todo_params)
ut.user = current_user
ut.is_owner = true
ut.save
```

current_user.todos_as_usertodos.first.is_owner?

You can make on user.rb

```
def todos_as_usertodos
  UserTodo.where(user_id: id).to_a
end
```

See where I'm going with this? You want to return and use UserTodo objects vs. Todo objects because they have more info in them. The info you need. That extra is_owner boolean. When you goto just a plain todo object you lose that info.

Answer (score 0):

That seems a bad way since you use .first to get your instance. I'll do something like

```
UserTodo.create(user: current_user, is_owner: true, todo: Todo.create(todo_params))
```

Second

I'm not sure if that is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-liner to create the join model with extra attributes:

```
current_user.user_todos.create(todo: Todo.create(todo_params), is_owner: true)
```

Since `is_owner` is an attribute of the join model, you have to access it through that model too:

```
current_user.user_todos.first.is_owner?
```